# need assistance debugging with BST validation function

Tags: c++

I was given this function to troubleshoot for an assignment but I can't figure out where its wrong, it seems to be doing the proper checking, please help?

```
bool validateBST(Node * root){
    if (root == nullptr){
        return true;
    }

    if (root->right != nullptr){
        if (root->value < root->right->value){
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateBST(root->right)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (root->left != nullptr){
        if (root->value > root->left->value){
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateBST(root->left)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that while it's checking the parent-child relationship, its not checking grandparent-grandchild relationship. specifically [something like this](https://postimg.org/image/wgslgfd6t/) is incorrect but would pass that validateBST function